# Lens and State, library inconsistencies

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskell-lens

I am trying to use lens to modify the state in a StateT Monad Transformer. As far as I understand, this code should compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens (makeLenses, (+=))
import Control.Monad.State (State)

data Game = Game {
    _player :: String,
    _points :: Int
} deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Game

play :: State Game ()
play = do
    points += 10
    return ()

main :: IO ()
main = undefined
```

But ghc tells me this:

```
No instance for (mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
                   Game
                   (Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT
                      Game Data.Functor.Identity.Identity))
  arising from a use of ‘+=’
...
```

I see that `mtl` may be the problem, so I type `ghc-pkg hide mtl`, and compile it again: no errors, it compiles!
I have the `transformers` library installed, so it's using that and that helps.

Then I change `State` to `StateT` by changing these two lines: `import Control.Monad.State (State)` -> `import Control.Monad.Trans.State (StateT)` and `play :: State Game ()` -> `play :: StateT Game IO ()`, and again, the compiler returns a similar error. What's going on?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 version of mtl installed? If so, make sure ghc is not using two different versions of mtl in one program.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do have two versions installed. But by using `ghc-pkg hide mtl` before compiling, I think it uses the transformers library.

Comment: Instead of invoking ghc directly, consider make a cabal package real quick and then building it with cabal.  If you have a dependency conflict, cabal will yell at you.  Hopefully that will make the problem more evident.

Comment: I tried building your program and it went without a hitch, so I'm fairly certain it's caused by your program using a different version of mtl than what lens uses.  The fact that GHC is reporting version numbers inside the error message is a huge red flag.  (Also, your program uses mtl directly so it's impossible to compile your program without mtl.)

Comment: Yeah, if a type error mentions a version number, there's almost certainly a package conflict going on.

Comment: I believe that `transformers` and `mtl` use somewhat different module names to avoid clashes, like `Control.Monad.State` vs. `Control.Monad.Trans.State`.

Comment: OK, I indeed had a broken package db, as confirmed using `ghc-pkg check`. I could fix things and now everything works. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Stephan: Don't forget to add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by fixing package inconsistencies, thanks to a hint by Rufflewind (see comment on my question above).

I first checked my existing package configuration with `ghc-pkg check`, and then used `ghc-pkg unregister --force` to remove all broken packages. I iteratively repeated it until no more broken packages were found. Then I reinstalled lens and now it works.